# CMake cannot link executable -ljsoncpp: no such file using github submodules

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, jsoncpp

I am working in a project which uses jsoncpp for parsing and cmake for compilation. I added the jsoncpp official git [repository](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) as a submodule to my project with `git submodule add REPO_URL external/jsoncpp`, so as to keep every dependency together.

When running `cmake -B out/build`, it works normally. But when I do `make`, I get the following error:

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljsoncpp: No such file or directory`.

The files are organized the following way:

```
- root
    - out/build
    - external
        - jsoncpp (cloned repo)
    - include
        foo.h
        bar.h
    - src
        foo.cpp
        bar.cpp
        main.cpp
    CMakeLists.txt
```

The CMakeLists.txt is like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)
project(ants)


# ".cpp" files in folder "src" into cmake variable "SOURCE"
file(GLOB SOURCE "src/*.cpp")

# Executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE})

# Directory where cmake will look for include files
include_directories(include)

# Tells cmake to compile jsoncpp
add_subdirectory(external/jsoncpp)
# Tells cmake where to look for jsoncpp include files
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    PUBLIC external/jsoncpp/include 
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} jsoncpp)
```

Comment: Are you sure cloned jsoncpp have its own CmakeLists.txt ?

Comment: I think you need to create some library from CmakeLists.txt inside jsoncpp directory using `add_library` and need to link that using `target_link_libraries` in your current CmakeLists.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jsoncppConfig.cmake` defines property `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` for targets `jsoncpp_lib` and `jsoncpp_lib_static`.

You need to query the target property and set it manually:

```
get_target_property(JSON_INC_PATH jsoncpp_lib INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
include_directories(${JSON_INC_PATH})
```

Linking is done via:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} jsoncpp_lib)
```

[Source](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/issues/455#issuecomment-477307969).

Try this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)
project(ants)

# ".cpp" files in folder "src" into cmake variable "SOURCE"
file(GLOB SOURCE "src/*.cpp")

# Executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE})

# Directory where cmake will look for include files
include_directories(include)

# Tells cmake to compile jsoncpp
add_subdirectory(external/jsoncpp)
get_target_property(JSON_INC_PATH jsoncpp_lib INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
include_directories(${JSON_INC_PATH})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} jsoncpp_lib)
```